# Why is the program running but debugging shows no count in the list?

Tags: c#

I am working on a console app in which I add members to a list through user input. The logic used is :

```
public class Projectlogic
    {
        public List<Project> Projects { get; set; } = new List<Project>();
         //Add a project to the list Projects.
        public void Add(Project project)
        {
            Projects.Add(project);
        }

        public List<Project> GetAllProjects()
        {
            return Projects;
        }

    }
```

The main program for adding a project to the list Projects is given below. When I debug the code, the count in Projects is shown as 0. What part of logic am I missing or using incorrectly?

```
//Adding parameters PID, Name, Sdate, Edate to a project.
var newProject = new Project(PID, Name, Sdate, Edate);
var business2 = new ProjectLogic(); //declared
business2.Add(newProject);
break;
```

Comment: Where are you stopping execution and inspecting the values?

Comment: _var business2 = new ProjectLogic(); //declared_ this is not just the declaration, this is also the initialization of a new instance of _ProjectLogic_ Every time the code reaches this point a _new_ instance of ProjectLogic is created with zero elements, then you add one but it is lost outside this block of code.

Comment: I used breakpoints after calling the method and when the program gets executed. The variable newProject shows a member, but the count remains zero after the Add method is called and executed.

Comment: Add a breakpoint in the `Add` method and check the count there. If it is one, you know there’s something wrong with your program.

Comment: that 'break' is very suspicous, can we see all the code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comments to the right (shortened the variable name to create more space):

```
var newProject = new Project(PID, Name, Sdate, Edate);


var b2 = new ProjectLogic(); //A new object with 0 items is created. 
                             //A breakpoint here will ALWAYS show zero items

b2.Add(newProject);         //Add the item, but the change won't show until the next line. 
                            //Breakpoints here will also ALWAYS show 0 items. 

break;                      //A breakpoint here will ALWAYS show ONE item.
                            //However, "break" will kick you out of the current scope.
                            //This means the business2 object also immediately goes
                            //out of scope and is thrown away.
```

Comment: Then, I would like to ask how can I save the element in the list because I can't perform any other operation in logic part as I am getting an empty list to work with.

Comment: You must declare the `ProjectLogic` variable in a larger scope, so the _same instance_ is used over time.